# How to set the color of a game object as of the other?

Tags: unity, c#, sprites, gameobject, color

I am 15 year old Indian student and I am creating my first 2D game in Unity. I have set the color of my player as Random and I have to set the color of my game object as of my player. But the color of the player changes Randomly. So I can't set a specific color to my game object.
What I have tried:

public class SetColor : MonoBehaviour {

```
public GameObject player;  
public SpriteRenderer sr;  
void Start() {  
     sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();  
     sr.color = Color.player;  
}
```

}

But this not worked. Please reply how to code it correctly?

Comment: Can I assume that `player` does already reference the player?

Comment: when the player respawn the color of the player is changed and I want the object to change color when the color of the player is changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class [`Color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html) has a couple predefined colors, but no color named "player". And the player itself doesn't have a color either. The player has a SpriteRenderer which has a color.

So what you need to do is obtain the SpriteRenderer component of the player and then the color from that SpriteRenderer.

```
 mySpriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();  
 playerSpriteRenderer = player.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();  
 mySpriteRenderer.color = playerSpriteRenderer.color;
```

Further, if you want the sprite to change color when the player changes color, then you shouldn't put the code into `Start`, you should put it into `Update`. This will update the color every frame. A more elegant and performance-friendly solution would only update the color when it actually changed, but that would make the above code a lot more complicated.  So I would recommend to do it this way for now to get started.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response

Comment: It worked as I wanted. I have spent 2 hours trying to solve this problem and atlast you saved my day.